# Java 8 Time API with Hibernate using millisecond / nanosecond precision

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a very simple entity, that uses the new Java 8 Time API.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "time")
    private LocalDateTime time;

    // ommitted
}
```

To properly support conversion, im using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

However, records in the database are saved like `2018-05-12 22:24:31`, which completely forgets the nanoseconds from `LocalTime`. I know that neither `Timestamp` nor `Date` can store nanoseconds, but i need at least millisecond precision. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

If relevant, I am using a MySQL database.

Comment: Timestamp can store milis, and from some version of mysql nanos as well

Comment: What is the SQL datatype of the column in the database?

Comment: @Andreas Its of type `datetime`

Comment: @Antoniossss Yeah, but somewhere on the way from LocalDateTime.now() to the database record the precision gets lost.

Comment: And what is column datatype?

Comment: @Antoniossss As previously commented, the column is of type datetime. The schema has been generated by Hibernate.

Comment: Timestamp(3) would store millisteconds. I think that you are loosing precision on DB not on service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change column type to

```
DATETIME(6)
```

as curently your second fraction is lost due to integer nature of `DATETIME`
Here you have MySQL documentation for that topic https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

Quoting

> DATETIME(fsp)
>
> The fsp value, if given, **must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0
>   signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default
>   precision is 0**. (This differs from the standard SQL default of 6, for
>   compatibility with previous MySQL versions.)

Comment: Yep, thats it! Out of curiosity, is there any way to let hibernate create the schema using a higher precision without depending on `columnDefinition = "DATETIME(x)"`? Then i would not depend on a specific database.

Comment: Just don't use hibernate to create schema for you but dedicated solutions  like liquibase for example

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me out!

Comment: I weird side effect is that if you try to persist an entity with non rounded date, MySQL will persist the value rounded, but if you query immediatelly Hibernate may return the date with the nanos! I believe it is because the data is cached in the persistence context.